# Getting text and sending it to a php function using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a php function which displays all the data in my mysql table and allows the user to delete data not needed. I managed to get the data to show in a table, get the delete button to ask for confirmation using javascript, but when i try to get the value in the 2nd cell of the table with the query result (the name) and display it on the confirmation tab, it says undefined. Why is that happening? From what i understand, `document.getElementById("myText").value` where myText is the id of the cell, should return the value in the cell, correct? Also, how would i call and send that value to another php file that has the delete query?

```
<?php

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr class='header'><td class='header'>Delete</td>";
    echo "<td class='header'>Added</td>";
    echo "<td class='header'>Name</td>";
    echo "<td class='header'>Genre</td>";
    echo "<td class='header'>Developer</td>";
    echo "<td class='header'>Rating</td></tr>";

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConfirmDelete(){
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        if (confirm("Delete" +name+"?")){
            //send the value and call the php
        }
    }
</script>

<?php

    for ($x=0; $row; $x++) {
        echo "<tr><td><input type='button' onclick='ConfirmDelete()' name='deleteGame' value='DELETE'></td><td>$row[Added]</td><td id='name'>$row[Name]</td><td>$row[Genre]</td><td>$row[Developer]</td><td align='right'>$row[Rating]</td></tr>";  
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    }

?>

</table>
```

Comment: The reason for "undefined" is because you're not using a unique ID. Your loop will probebly return several rows with `id='name'`. IDs are supposed to be unique. So whenever you call `getElementById('name')`, it'll return the first row with that ID only. Every next row with the same ID will never be "defined". I can't answer the rest of your question without more information. The solution would be to use ajax techniques, probebly best in combination with jQuery. But to be able to write an example I need to know the db rows unique key.

Comment: my database doesnt have a unique key. I have never used ajax or jquery before.

Comment: Ofcourse it does. You can't have a db table without a unique key. It's probebly 'id' auto_increment or something like that.

Comment: ok, well how do i find the unique? I only learned the basic and am using phpmyadmin to access my mysql db.

Comment: Just give me the structure of you table. It should be something like: `'id','Added','Name','Genre','Developer','Rating'`. All the column names basicly.

Comment: `'Added``Name``Genre``Age_Rating``Console``Developer``About``Trailer``Cover``Rating`. The only column that would be unique per-say is the name.

Comment: I think you're going to need more in dept help with this since you lack the nessesary knowledge to program something like this. Please click on my name to visit my profile. You'll find my email address there. Send me an email to continue from there on as comments are not supposed to turn into a chat.